# How can I determine which commands are installed by default on Ubuntu, CentOS and Red Hat?

Tags: ubuntu, centos, rhel

I was surprised to discover that curl didn't come bundled as part of Ubuntu.  Is there a canonical list of included <strike>components</strike> Linux commands that I can check for these three operating systems?

Comment: since CentOS is essentially just a recompiled version of RHEL, they should be pretty similar. Of course, the definition of "default" may vary user by user, depending on what kind of install they're doing - desktop, server, devel, etc.

Answer (score 2):

https://askubuntu.com/a/50127

> Every *buntu release has a `.manifest` or `.list` file that lists
>   pre-installed packages. This file is located online.
>
> For example:
>
> Ubuntu 12.04.2 32bit ➜
>   http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.manifest
>
> Ubuntu 11.04 32bit ➜
>   http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.manifest
>
> Ubuntu 11.04 64bit ➜
>   http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.manifest
>
> Kubuntu 11.04 32bit ➜
>   http://releases.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/11.04/kubuntu-11.04-desktop-i386.list
>
> ...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be on a Debian system, or a Debian based system you can do;

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | awk '($2 !~ /deinstall/) { print $0}'
```

Which will give you a list of installed applications.

As far as "components" are concerned, you'll have to define what you mean by that. In Debian / Ubuntu and likely in the RHEL world a package is roughly synonymous with a component.

Comment: Sorry - corrected terminology.  I'm looking for a list of *commands*.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
ls /bin
ls /usr/bin
ls /usr/local/bin
```

Or a more fancy all-in-1:

```
ls -d -1 {/usr/bin/,/bin/,/usr/local/bin}** | more
```

EDIT.

Ups, I missed the original question.

Comment: I'm not actually on the system in question.  I just need to know if  a standard (say) Desktop Ubuntu installation will have command "XXX" installed by default.